# Main form got stuck when thread doing Ping test

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm making multithread based ping tester.

So, I added few IP's to ListView control, and made one BackgroundWorkers per item.
After all, I started program, and when I started to ping, main form's form controls are got stuck and didn't respond until all ping's end(include time expired pings). Here are entire source.
(I designed form with Form Designer GUI)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace Multi_Ping_Tester
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        //List<Thread> pingThreads = new List<Thread>();

       private void doPing(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Ping pingsender = new Ping();
            PingReply pingres;
            int idx = (int)e.Argument;

            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                string addr = lvwIPList.Items[idx].Text;

                //do
                //{
                pingres = pingsender.Send(addr);

                if (pingres.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    lvwIPList.Items[idx].SubItems[1].Text = pingres.RoundtripTime.ToString();
                    lvwIPList.Items[idx].BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                }
                else
                {
                    lvwIPList.Items[idx].SubItems[1].Text = "Nein";
                    lvwIPList.Items[idx].BackColor = Color.LightPink;
                }
                //} while(true);
            }));
        }


        List<BackgroundWorker> bgwList = new List<BackgroundWorker>();

        private void ResizeCol()
        {
            chdIP.Width = (int)((lvwIPList.Width - 6) * 0.8);
            chdRTT.Width = (int)((lvwIPList.Width - 6) * 0.2);
        }
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ResizeCol();
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lvwIPList.Items.Add(txtIP.Text);
            lvwIPList.FindItemWithText(txtIP.Text).SubItems.Add("");
        }

        private void btnPing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 /*           pingThreads.Clear();
            int idx=0;
*/
            bgwList.Clear();
            int idx = 0;

            foreach (ListViewItem i in lvwIPList.Items)
            {
                /*
                pingThreads.Add(new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(doPing)));
                pingThreads[idx].IsBackground = true;
                pingThreads[idx].Start(idx);
                idx++;
                */
                bgwList.Add(new BackgroundWorker());
                bgwList[idx].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(doPing);
                bgwList[idx].RunWorkerAsync(idx);
                idx++;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Some commented lines are using Threads, but it makes same result.
What could be problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're calling the `ping.Send` inside `this.Invoke`, `Invoke` will execute the delegate synchronously in UI thread and thus it freezes the UI.

You should be doing it outside the `this.Invoke`, or use `await Ping.SendAsync`. Of course if you plan to await, you need to do it in an `async` method. In your case you need an `async` lambda.

Comment: Thanks. As you said, I used ping outside of Invoke, and it works just like what I wanted.